# Application-scope Variables in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, variables, scope

Is there a variable scope in Node.js that persists longer than the request, that is available to all application users? I'd like to create a variable that can be read/written to by multiple app users, like so:

```
var appScope.appHitCount += 1;
```

The session scope won't work because it is user specific. Looking for application specific. I couldn't find anything in the Node.js docs. Thanks.

Comment: `express()` app object provides the [_app.locals_](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.locals) property to store local variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a variable scoped to the app module it will be available and shared by everything within the scope. I imagine in a big app you would need to be careful with this, but it's just regular javascript scoping. For example this will continue to append to the array as you hit it:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
var input = []

app.get('/:input/', (req, res) => {
    var params = req.params
    input.push(params.input)
    res.send("last input was: " + JSON.stringify(input))
})

app.listen(8080, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 8080!'))
```

Now visiting 'http://localhost:8080/hi' returns:

> last input was: ["hi"]

and then 'http://localhost:8080/there' returns:

> last input was: ["hi", "there"]

...etc.

If you want something shared by the entire app (i.e. all the modules) you could set up a module that is `require()`d by all the modules and i=has the responsibility of getting and setting that value.